# What is a convention for having multiple classes with same names in Java

Tags: java, architecture, naming-conventions

Let's say I have a Product class for an api1 in Java:
`com.api1.products.Product`.
Then I want to create a new version 2 of this api where Product has different fields, and existing fields have other types, so that Product v1 and Product v2 are not compatible at all.
What is the best and clean way to do this?
Options I see:

1. Just name `ProductApi1` and `ProductApi2` and so on? I use this method now, but it feels a bit awkward. Besides such a naming implies an implementation - I always thought it's a bad practice. But it just works.
2. Have same name `Product` but in different packages: `com.api1.products.Product`, `com.api2.products.Product`. This seems ok, but when one reads the code it's almost impossible to tell which `Product` is used without looking at packages or using fully qualified names. With fully qualified name code becomes ugly I think.

Are there any other ideas on this or conventions? The goal is to have same object in different versions of api without introducing unnecessary complexity.

I guess this question may be a bit subjective but I believe it still implies architecture and coding practices.

Comment: You could use API versioning. For example, for a REST API: https://restfulapi.net/versioning/

Comment: @JustAnotherDeveloper It's not about api versioning itself - it's about implementation of this versioning inside my code.

Comment: Hmmmm... Fair. Do both `Product` classes share any common properties? You could have them extend a `BaseProduct` class if so, and just treat everything as a `BaseProduct`when needed, and think of more meaningful names than `ProductApi1` and `ProductApi2` for the subclasses, and put them in different packages. But ultimately this is an issue with naming and your personal preferences ("I think the code becomes ugly when...", "I always thought it's bad practice...").

Comment: Having different packages is a good choice since you can always remove the entire package and write a testcase checking on the class version which you support in api.The approach works like a charm if frequency of changes is high